# Does a landlord have to tell you the reason for entering your apartment?

Tags: rental-property, landlord, rhode-island

Today a "representative of the investors" in my apartment complex entered my apartment for an inspection. As the inspector was leaving he said to me that I passed the inspection, but just barely. I asked him what that meant and if there were specific inspection criteria he was looking for, but he declined to answer.

Afterwards, I contacted the apartment management office, and was told that they weren't told what was being inspected, just that someone would be entering apartments.

I was just wondering if there is any reason a landlord has to tell you why they are entering the property you're renting, or if with sufficient notice they can simply enter for any reason. I assume this could potentially differ on a state by state basis, so general knowledge is fine. I live in RI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In RI it appears that two days notice and a reasonable purpose is enough. There are states that list the *reasons* a landlord can access a unit; RI is not one of those states.

http://webserver.rilin.state.ri.us/Statutes/title34/34-18/34-18-26.HTM

Answer (score 1):

You do not give a jurisdiction; as tenancy law is one of the most regulated areas of law this is *highly* jurisdiction dependent and may vary depending on if it is a residential or commercial tenancy.

For example, in New South Wales, Australia, a landlord may enter a residential premises (http://www.tenants.org.au/factsheet-08-access-and-privacy):

- With consent of the tenant
- Without consent or notice:

  - in an emergency, or
  - to do urgent repairs, or
  - if the landlord thinks that the premises have been abandoned, or
  - in accordance with an order of the NSW Civil and Administrative Tribunal (NCAT), or
  - if they have serious concern about the health/safety of a person on the premises (after they have first tried to get consent).
- Without consent but with notice (periods vary) and within limitations:

  - To inspect the premises
  - To carry out or assess the need for:

    - necessary repairs/maintenance (non-urgent)
    - work to meet legal health/safety obligations
  - To value the premises
  - To show the premises to prospective tenants
  - To show the premises to prospective buyers

Comment: The last sentence of the question gives the jurisdiction as Rhode Island, US, as does the tag. And the word "apartment" strongly suggests a residential tenancy.